# how to multiply between decimal and textinput in php?

Tags: php, mysql, decimal, textinput, multiplication

```
 $number=$_REQUEST['number'];
 $price=$row2['costpeople'];
 $endprice=$price*$number;
```

number is the name of input, type of this input is "TEXT" and costpeople is a field of database that type of this field is decimal. when multiply Between price and number and echo $endprice don't show the value of $endprice. This means that don't multiply Between them, please help me. its Necessary for me.

Comment: where are you printing $endprice ? Also show the full code .. we can't assume where the problem is ..

Comment: $endprice=$price*$number;die($endprice); but don't show anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$number = floatval($_REQUEST['number']);
$price = $row2['costpeople'];
$endprice=$price*$number;
```

you can use floatval(), intval() to convert string to number.. [source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)

[You can also do type cast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue of `TEXT` here my sample code working fine and return me output well.

```
$a = "5.5";
$b = "5";
echo $a*$b;
//Result 27.5
```

Comment: @Neda check my sample code it work fine why your code not work?